# Change default configuration file of Symfony2 project

Tags: php, symfony, command

#### Context

I have a simple Symfony2 project (only command line commands). This project includes an `app/config.yml` file, containing information used for dependency injection creation.

For example, `app/config.yml` contains:

```
github:
    token: abcdefgh
```

And `src/Foo/Resources/config/github.yml` (services files) contains:

```
services:
    github.client:
        class: Github\Client
        calls:
            - ['authenticate', [%github.token%, null, 'http_token']]
```

The file `app/config.yml` is loaded by `Application::__construct()` function.

When I run `app/console mycommand`, it uses the defined token.

#### Needs

I need to be able to run my commands using different configurations.
For now, I replace manually the `app/config.yml` file, but it's crappy.

To do this, I thought about 2 possible solutions:

- Be able to specify another `app/config.yml` file when I run `app/console mycommand --f=app/config2.yml`.
- Have another configuration file for specific command usage, and use it with `app/console mycommand --f=myconfig.yml`. The thing is the dependency injection can not work or be updated after the application is run.

I don't know how to do one of this solution (or a third one, no matters). If it's a common behavior, can you point me some documentation or example to do something like this?

Comment: This looks like a fine question, but please do not add meta commentary. I am presently suspending my rule that questions begging for a refrainment of downvotes immediately get one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is totally possible by using different environements, check out the doc :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/environments.html

Typically you will specify the environement using --env=myenv.

Comment: Hei @NathanVss ! Thanks for your answer. Change the environment looks like a little workaround, but this gave me an idea. I just updated my Application to add a new option changing the config file. In fact, I don't have any Kernel in this application.

Comment: Oh, I see. So, do you need more informations or it is ok ?